# Label dataframe column with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe(**original_df**) with column `description`, and I want to create another column `Label` by searching for keyword in the description using regular expression e.g

```
description                   Label

fund trf 0049614823          transfers
alat transfer                transfers
data purchase via            airtime
alat pos buy                  pos
alat web buy                 others
atm wd rch debit money       withdrawals
alat pos buy                  pos
salar alert charges          salary
mtn purchase via             airtime
top- up purchase via         airtime
```

The psedocode I came up with was

1. Input- description column and regular expression
2. Use the regular expression to search for patterns in the `description` column
3. loop through the `description` and create a label based on the
   description keyword
4. return the full dataframe with label column

I tried implementing that  here but I didn't get the logic right and I am getting a keyword error
I have also tried all that I could possibly do at the moment but still can't come up with the right logic

```
df = original_df['description'].sample(100)

position = 0


while position < len(df):
    
    if any(re.search(r"(tnf|trsf|trtr|trf|transfer)",df[position])):
        original_df['Label'] == 'transfers'
    
    
        
    elif any(re.search(r'(airtime|data|vtu|recharge|mtn|glo|top-up)',df[position])):
         original_df['Label'] == 'aitime
    
    
    elif  any(re.search(r'(pos|web pos|)',df[position])):
        original_df['Label'] == 'pos
                   
    elif  any(re.search(r'(salary|sal|salar|allow|allowance)',df[position])):
         original_df['Label'] == 'salary'
    
                    
    elif  any(re.search(r'(loan|repayment|lend|borrow)',df[position])):
        original_df['Label'] == 'loan'
        
                    
    elif  any(re.search(r'(withdrawal|cshw|wdr|wd|wdl|withdraw|cwdr|cwd|cdwl|csw)',df[position])):
        return 'withdrawals'
    
    position += 1

    return others

                    
print(df_sample)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your regex logic into a function and `apply` that to the DataFrame. This way you can avoid your manual looping pseudocode.

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'description': [
    'fund trf 0049614823',
    'alat transfer',
    'data purchase via',
    'alat pos buy',
    'alat web buy',
    'atm wd rch debit money',
    'alat pos buy',
    'salar alert charges',
    'mtn purchase via',
    'top- up purchase via',
]})
```

|  | description |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | fund trf 0049614823 |
| 1 | alat transfer |
| 2 | data purchase via |
| 3 | alat pos buy |
| 4 | alat web buy |
| 5 | atm wd rch debit money |
| 6 | alat pos buy |
| 7 | salar alert charges |
| 8 | mtn purchase via |
| 9 | top- up purchase via |

Create a `label()` function based on your regex code:

```py
import re
def label(row):
    if re.search(r'(tnf|trsf|trtr|trf|transfer)', row.description):
        result = 'transfers'
    elif re.search(r'(airtime|data|vtu|recharge|mtn|glo|top-up)', row.description):
        result = 'airtime'
    elif re.search(r'(pos|web pos)', row.description):
        result = 'pos'
    elif re.search(r'(salary|sal|salar|allow|allowance)', row.description):
        result = 'salary'
    elif re.search(r'(loan|repayment|lend|borrow)', row.description):
        result = 'loan'
    elif re.search(r'(withdrawal|cshw|wdr|wd|wdl|withdraw|cwdr|cwd|cdwl|csw)', row.description):
        result = 'withdrawals'
    else:
        result = 'other'
    return result
```

Then `apply` the `label()` function to the rows of `df`:

```py
df['label'] = df.apply(label, axis=1)
```

|  | description | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | fund trf 0049614823 | transfers |
| 1 | alat transfer | transfers |
| 2 | data purchase via | airtime |
| 3 | alat pos buy | pos |
| 4 | alat web buy | pos |
| 5 | atm wd rch debit money | pos |
| 6 | alat pos buy | pos |
| 7 | salar alert charges | pos |
| 8 | mtn purchase via | airtime |
| 9 | top- up purchase via | pos |